# jgraphx change vertex size

Tags: java, swing, jgraphx

I draw a simple graph (using Java swing interface).

The graph is OK, but the default / automatic vertices size is small for my purpose. How to set the vertex size (rectangle or ellipse)?

I can change some graph behavior using  put() ( like `put(mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE, mxConstants.SHAPE_ELLIPSE))` but not the size of vertices.

The graph is OK, but the default / automatic vertices size is small for my purpose. How to set the vertex size (rectangle or ellipse)?

May I have misunderstood many about jgraphx?

The documentation is very difficult to understand, very cryptic (at least for me), can I have suggestions for  books or links for better understand jgraphx for Java.

One more detail: the graph isn't built  element by element, but  it come from a graph built with jgraphT using jGraphXAdapter

`JGraphXAdapter<Incrocio, Strada> graphAdapter = 
  new JGraphXAdapter<Incrocio, Strada>(listenableGraph);`

Comment: *"The documentation is very difficult to understand"* Link to the docs for the class being used.

Comment: I've made one step ahead. I can change vertex size changing the cells geometry: 
I have to iterate every cell, check if is a vertex, an apply the new size with

`mxGeometry geometry = cell.getGeometry();.
geometry.setWidth(); geometry.set Height();`

The displayed graph has the new size, but selecting a vertex (with double click of mouse on the  vertex's figure) and removing selection, the vertex is redrawn to the previous size.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: *"Any suggestion is appreciated."* 1) I already gave you one. 2) Following advice is appreciated. Ignoring the advice will likely see you ignored by the people trying to help (for free).

Comment: Sorry, but I've not understood your suggestion.
Can you be more precise? Thanks.

Comment: *"..I've not understood your suggestion."* Did you **think** you understood it when you made the 1st reply? What was your understanding at that moment? *"Can you be more precise?"* Sure I can, but I'm not going to, yet. Not until I discover the basis behind why you replied to a comment without understanding the simple message it contained. After all, if you cannot understand a 10 word sentence, there is a high probability you will not understand a more detailed explanation. Why waste my time?

Comment: I'm sorry, now I understand.
I'm using  this documentation: [link] (https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/java/docs/index.html)  , [link] (https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/manual_javavis.html)

 classes: _mxGeometry_  and _mxStylesheet_

Comment: OK.. progress. Concentrating on the first link to the JavaDocs for the entire API. I asked for the link to the (Java) docs. for the specific **`class`** being used (to make the graph). The documentation lists 234 classes, so I'm hoping you can narrow it down. Maybe the information to solve this problem is not in that class itself, but it would be a good starting point. So.. when you write the code statement for a `new (graph)` what is the exact class name that should replace `(graph)`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank to Andrew for her patience. 
English is not my language, and sometime I make a mistakes even in italian (my native language). Add that I'm new in Java. New even in this forum (an related rules, and this may not be the right place for my replay).  I've not read your message previous with the due attention.

I put the code, whith a partial solution, I hope it's more clear.

```
package it.rex.view;

public class StradarioViewBis2 extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    // listenableGraph is a complete graph done with JgraphT
    public StradarioViewBis2(ListenableGraph<Incrocio, Strada> listenableGraph) {

        JGraphXAdapter<Incrocio, Strada> graphAdapter = 
                new JGraphXAdapter<Incrocio, Strada>(listenableGraph);

        //graphAdapter.getStylesheet().getDefaultEdgeStyle().put(mxConstants.STYLE_NOLABEL, "1");  //remove label from edge

        graphAdapter.getModel().beginUpdate();
        try {
            graphAdapter.clearSelection(); 
            graphAdapter.selectAll();
            Object[] cells = graphAdapter.getSelectionCells(); //here you have all cells

            // Iterate into graph to change cells
            for (Object c : cells) {
                mxCell cell = (mxCell) c; //cast
                mxGeometry geometry = cell.getGeometry();

                if (cell.isVertex()) { //isVertex
                    // Here I can change vertex dimensions 
                    geometry.setWidth(40);
                    geometry.setHeight(40);
                }else{ //is not a vertex, so u can get source and target 
                    //  cell.setStyle("orthogonalEdgeStyle"); 
                    //  cell.getChildAt(x); //Returns the child at the specified index. (target)
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            graphAdapter.getModel().endUpdate();
        }

        mxIGraphLayout layout = new mxCircleLayout(graphAdapter);  // questo sistema le posizione degli elementi

        layout.execute(graphAdapter.getDefaultParent());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 550, 450);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graphAdapter);  // is JScrollPane extension 

        graphComponent.setPageVisible(true);
        graphComponent.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
        contentPane.add(graphComponent);

        //graphComponent.setEnabled(false);
        graphComponent.getViewport().setBackground(Color.white);
        ;

    }

}
```

After some tries, I've found that the vertex's size is back to initial dimension when I change the cell's label, not when I move the focus away from cell.

I think I need to change the default behavior of the graph, but i'm not yet discovered how.

This is the result, after editing label on top vetex:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7B4z.png)